# I can not create a folder in php

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I'm developing an application that creates a folder by pressing a button if a certain condition is met. the issue is that the folder is created using the mkdir () and do not understand why. even the html page tells me that the folder was created, but this does not appear in the directory. I do not understand the error. the code is as follows:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>RHM</title> 
   <style type="text/css">
      h1 { color: red; font-family: arial; font-size: 3em; font-weight: bolder; }
      p { color: navy; font-family: Verdana; }
   </style>
 </head>

 <body>
     <h1 align="center">INGRESE CONTRASE&Ntilde;A</h1>

     <form  action="#" method="post" >
        <p align="center"> <input type="password" name="contras" style="width:200px;height:50px;background-color:yellow;color:blue;font-size:14pt;font-family: Comic Sans MS;text-align:center;padding-right:10px;"/></p>
        <p align="center"  ><input type="submit" value="Entrar" /></p>

     <?php
        $Contraseña=$_POST['contras'];
        $estructura = "/home/bladimir/RHMbd";
        if ($Contraseña==1) {
            mkdir($estructura);
            echo "<p>La carpeta fue creada</p>";
        }
     ?>

     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank.

Comment: When you say « but this does not appear in the directory », are you checking server side or client side ? Does the php user have rights on the directory to create sub directories ?

Comment: you should specify third params recursive true to mkdir

Comment: You may want to share the error as well. Presumably, you don’t have writing access to `/home/bladimir`. Check the permissions of that folder, the writing access specifically.

Comment: you are getting `La carpeta fue creada` because `$Contraseña==1` is becoming true its  not checking that directory is created ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have permission to create the directory.

Go to the folder  /private/etc/apache2

Open httpd.conf

Find

```
User _www 
Group _www
```

Change the username:

```
User <YOUR LOGIN USERNAME>
```

Restart apache.

Comment: 0777 is default even if you don't specify it will be taken by default

Comment: just try the above code, replace it by your code and tell me if it works

Comment: The server is located locally on my computer. Add a third recursive parameter does not work. The suggested code does not work.

Comment: I'm using debian 7 and eclipse on a 64bit pc. The directory / private / etc / apache2 httpd.conf file and do not exist in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['contras']))
    {
        $Contraseña = $_POST['contras'];
        $estructura = "c:://home/bladimir/RHMbd";

        $dir = dirname($estructura);

        if (!is_dir($dir))
        {
            var_dump(mkdir($dir, 0777, true));
            if ($Contraseña == '1')
            {
                echo 'fsdf';
                mkdir($estructura);
                echo "<p>La carpeta fue creada</p>";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by giving the appropriate permissions to the user with the following command in console: chmod a + w bladimir. Thank for all.